# Using multithreading to find the maximum number of keys encountered in multiple linkedlists

Tags: c, multithreading, linked-list, heap

I have a many (about 60000) linked-lists consisting of nodes with increasing sorted keys. The keys only occur once in each linked-list, but they could be repeated in different linked-lists. Each linked-list has keys from 0 to 4000 (or some other big number). a sample of the linked-list is as follows (although this is a very small sample).

index 0: 1->3->9->212->400

index 1: 6->12->212->231->600

index 2: NULL

index 3: 2->3->1632

index 4: 1->3->45

index 5: 1000->3212

...

input is a set of numbers which corresponds to the linked-list indexes, such as 
0, 3, 4

the output is the key that has been repeated the most in the given indexes. In this case the output is 3 (as it has been repeated in all three linked-lists).

This problem can be solved using a sequential algorithm; going through each list and keeping track of the keys in a priority queue/max-heap where the beginning of the queue/root of the max-heap has the key with the most number of hits.

Because this is a big scale problem, I want to leverage the power of multithreading and solve this problem in a manner that would be faster than sequential, avoiding mutex if possible as to avoid performance hit. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is quite simplistic approach using a `ConcurrentDictionary`. The solution does not depend on the lists being sorted or that a value can appear at most one time in a list. Also, I have replaced the `null` list with an empty collection to simplify the code.

```
var data = new Dictionary<Int32, IEnumerable<Int32>> {
  { 0, new[] { 1, 3, 9, 212, 400 } },
  { 1, new[] { 6, 12, 212, 231, 600 } },
  { 2, Enumerable.Empty<Int32>() },
  { 3, new[] { 2, 3, 1632 } },
  { 4, new[] { 1, 3, 45 } },
  { 5, new[] { 1000, 3212 } }
};
var input = new[] { 0, 3, 4 };
var counts = new ConcurrentDictionary<Int32, Int32>();
Parallel.ForEach(
  input.SelectMany(key => data[key]),
  key => counts.AddOrUpdate(key, k => 1, (k, count) => count + 1)
);
var maxCount = counts.OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value).First().Value;
var results = counts
  .Where(kvp => kvp.Value == maxCount)
  .Select(kvp => kvp.Key)
  .ToList();
```

To be able to correctly handle empty input the code should be modified slightly to use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First` but doing that here just clutters the code.

I do not know if this code is particular efficient because there will be a lot of contention for the lock in the `ConcurrentDictionary` so you should probably measure performance to get a better understanding.